# What is the difference between :change and v-on:change in vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue.js

I have two v-model

case 1:

```
<input type="date" v-model="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" v-on:change="onDateChange()">
<input type="text" v-model="editForm.u1" class="form-control" id="u1" placeholder="U1">
```

this works fine

case 2:

```
<input type="date" v-model="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" :change="onDateChange()">
<input type="text" v-model="editForm.u1" class="form-control" id="u1" placeholder="U1">
```

In this even changing u1 triggers onDateChange();

Answer (score 9):

`:change` binds the attribute, as in `v-bind:change="onDateChange()"`

`@change="onDateChange()` is the shorthand syntax for `v-on`.